# Question about Toadfist's Helm in Drakan (PS2)

Tags: ps2, drakan-the-ancients-gates

I'm playing Drakan on PS2 and I just realized I missed Toadfist's Helm and can't go back for it. (I'm trying to decide if its worth restarting the game for.)

I know it's worth 2,000 gold to the blacksmith, but I'm wondering if that's all? Can you wear it? If so, what are its stats?

(I've already looked around all over the internet and can't find anything that answer's my question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth 2000 gold and that's **it**.
 It is mentioned as an artifact in the categories on the official wiki, and you can not wear an artifact.

[Source 1](http://drakan.wikia.com/wiki/Toadfist%27s_Helm)